# Error while calling the phtml file in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I created a multiselect attribute with label `featuredetails`.
I created a static block and called the `feature.phtml` file(a newly created phtml file) in it like:

```
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
      <p>{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/feature.phtml"}}</p>
</div>
```

The content of the phtml file is:

```
    <?php       
   $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
?>

<div class="feature">

    <?php
        $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
        ->getAttribute('featuredetails')->getFrontend()
        ->getValue($_product));
        foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
            <?php echo "<img   src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
       </a>

       <?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
```

The content of the block will map the attributes with the media images.

But am getting error like: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean`

Help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attribute isn't created or attribute_code is mismatch. Please try to find attribute with attribute_code `featuredetails` in Attribute Grid.

Please check the following code with your attribute_code

```
$attributeInstance = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'featuredetails');
var_dump($attributeInstance->getId());
```

As a result you should see `attribute_id`.

Comment: should i include this in my code?